# Confused about the Drude model

Tags: electric-current, electrical-resistance, conductors, plasma-physics

I was thinking about the Hall conductivity, when this question popped up. If there is a magnetic field and an electric field perpendicular to it, then a Hall current is generated since the ions have larger gyro radii compared to electrons. Now this current would produce a $\vec J \times \vec B$ force in the direction of the electric field. This means that if electrons have sufficient thermal energy in a plasma, they can create a current that pushes them in the direction of the electric field. Would this result in a negative conductivity if it were strong enough?

But solving the drude model equation doesn't give us a negative conductivity anywhere.

So, I was wondering if the effect is not strong enough to result in negative conductivity or whether the Drude model does not consider the $\vec J \times \vec B$ force. I always thought the momentum-magnetic field cross product term was the $\vec J \times \vec B$ force.

Comment: Wait, so the current-carrying electrons are going to create an electric field that acts on themselves?  The current arises because the electrons can still ExB-drift but the ions become demagnetized, thus causing a relative drift between the two species, which is a current.  If that current flows across the magnetic field, then there will be a JxB force, but it's kind of circular.  Suppose V is to the right and B is out of the page, then E will be upwards.  The ExB-drift is then parallel to V (which it should be) and is V.

Comment: J = - ne$V_{ExB}$, which is parallel to E.  So the particles try to ExB-drift to the right but are deflected upwards in the plane, thus the Hall effect.

Comment: If you meant velocity by v. Then, for example if we have a radial magnetic field and an electric field perpendicular to it, wouldn't the J cross B drift push the electrons in the direction of E? I was wondering if this effect is already included in the drudes model.

Comment: the J comes from the hall current. Is this right?

Comment: The electrons undergo an ExB-drift and the ions do not.  If you assume the ions are stationary (as they are in solids) then the only velocity is the ExB-drift velocity of electrons, which is anti-parallel to the corresponding current (yes, the Hall current).  In the example I gave, the JxB vector would lie along the E-field, yes.

Comment: In that case wouldn't the conductivity along the electric field be negative? Is this J cross B force not strong enough or is it not included in the drude model? Is the momentum cross B term in the drude equation this effect?

Comment: Why negative?  The Drude model is basically a starting point of the generalized Ohm's law.  It is actually a different term in Ohm's law, one given by $\eta \mathbf{j}$ where $\eta$ is a scalar resistivity (should be a tensor to be general, but that's just details).